# Convert Sprite x,y, width, height into view port rect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this function where i want to convert my sprite x, y, width, height into view port rect so that i can set it to my camera.

```
void SetImageRectToCameraRect() {
        float x = sideCameraMask.rectTransform.rect.x;
        float y = sideCameraMask.rectTransform.rect.y;
        float width = sideCameraMask.rectTransform.rect.width;
        float height = sideCameraMask.rectTransform.rect.height;
        Debug.Log(x);
        Debug.Log(y);
        Debug.Log(width);
        Debug.Log(height);
        Debug.Log(sideCamGUI.bounds.size.x);
        Debug.Log(sideCamGUI.bounds.size.y);
        Debug.Log(sideCamGUI.bounds.size);
        Vector3 v3 = GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToViewportPoint(new Vector3(x,y,0));//x,y,0f
        Debug.Log("ScreenToViewportPoint::" + v3);

        camComponent.rect = new Rect(x, y, width, height);

    }
```

The problem is that how do I convert width and height into camera view port width height

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're working in 2D and using an orthographic camera. A perspective camera makes things more complicated.

To get the percentage (fraction) of the viewport that the sprite takes up, you'd divide `width` and `height` by the camera's width and height respectively.

```
float camHeight = camera.orthographicSize * 2;
float camWidth = camHeight * camera.aspect;

float heightFraction = height / camHeight;
float widthFraction = width / camWidth;
```

If you're using [`Camera.rect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-rect.html) (which I think is the case) just use `widthFraction` and `heightFraction` directly. If you're using [`Camera.pixelRect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-pixelRect.html), multiply `widthFraction` and `heightFraction` by `Camera.pixelWidth` and `Camera.pixelHeight` respectively.

If you want the width and height only of the area *visible* by the camera, you'll have to perform a bounds intersection which should be trivial to implement.